# Generate HTML to custom PDF in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdf

For my Angular web application, I look for a library so that I can get the content of some sites (without the side-bar) on a PDF in DIN A4 format, and to that PDF there should i.e. also always be a table applied automatically which retrieves its data from the components' TypeScript file. So I just want to be able not just to print 1:1 what you see on the page, but insert custom elements and put in the data that sits in the component TypeScript. Do you have recommendations which libraries can do that on client-side? In the end you should be able to download the PDF.

Comment: Why isn't this question suitable for Stack overflow: seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche oh I see, thanks, maybe I should post that somewhere else and delete here. Do you know a suitable forum for this kind of question?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I usually do an extensive Google search and try to find articles from people who have actually implemented things. So far I haven't been too disappointed with that technique :)